# How to calculate finger width programmatically if I press a finger on the screen?

Tags: android, multi-touch, ontouchlistener, motionevent

I need to **calculate the width of each of finger** when I  press a finger on the screen and I want the app to detect the size.

What I've done:

- When I pressed the finger on the screen and drew the finger according to pressed area but **onTouchListener** will work after move it on screen.
- getPressure () method available in **MotionEvent** but it returns the ***int***, not worthy.
- Apply MultiTouchEvent, also not working well.

Please suggest how to achieve this or if one of above ways will also be helpful to make it worthy, suggest me.